# MySQL query to SQL Server query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I defined sql query and it runs with no problem on MySQL (I am using MySQL) , but when I am trying to execute it on client site (they uses SQL Server)
I am getting "Error: Incorrect syntax near 'si'." error message

Hope someone can help me to define right syntax.

The query is following:

```
update stepinstance si
     inner join cesteplink l on si.id = l.stepinstance_id 
     inner join prompt p on si.prompt_id = p.id
set si.principal_id = 29160180  
where l.case_id = 29179541 
  and si.principal_id = 1799409 
  and si.status = 'In Progress'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` has to be before the `join` conditions.

```
update si
set si.principal_id = 29160180 
from stepinstance si
inner join cesteplink l on si.id = l.stepinstance_id 
inner join prompt p on si.prompt_id = p.id 
where l.case_id = 29179541 
and si.principal_id = 1799409 
and si.status = 'In Progress'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am using Squirrel to run quesrie, and was confused when it complained to "from", I just ignored and run, and it update record